# What does 'interior initial conditions' and 'interior boundary conditions' stand for?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

My question concerns on the word 'interior' in the IVP and BVP problems. How do we describe the conditions with 'interior' mathematically? I know the difference between IVP and BVP, but it would be really helpful if somebody can provide me with the interior initial conditions and interior boundary conditions, say for the well-known **wave equation**.

Comment: I have not seen the word ‘interior’ being used to describe ICs or BCs in this way. Where have you seen this?

Comment: While solving for the wave equation in an elastic medium and also in Schrodinger's wave equation.

Comment: Please can you give a reference where you've seen the expression, so that we can see it being used in the context?